# BitConverter.ToInt32 to convert 2 bytes

Tags: c#, .net

I am using  BitConverter.ToInt32 to convert a Byte array into int.

I have only two bytes [0][26], but the function needs 4 bytes, so I have to add two 0 bytes to the front of the existing bytes.

What is the quickest method.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably do `(int)BitConverter.ToInt16(..)` instead.  `ToInt16` is made to read two bytes into a `short`.   Then you simply convert that to an `int` with the cast.

Comment: Might want to make a note about endianess however.

Answer (score 2):

You should call `BitConverter.ToInt16, which only reads two bytes.

`short` is implicitly  convertible to `int`.

Answer (score 1):

`Array.Copy`. Here is some code:

```
byte[] arr = new byte[] { 0x12, 0x34 };
byte[] done = new byte[4];
Array.Copy(arr, 0, done, 2, 2); // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z50k9bft.aspx
int myInt = BitConverter.ToInt32(done); // 0x00000026
```

However, a call to `BitConverter.ToInt16(byte[]) seems like a better idea, then just save it to an int:

```
int myInt = BitConverter.ToInt16(...);
```

Keep in mind endianess however. On little endian machines, `{ 0x00 0x02 }` is actually 512, not 2 (`0x0002` is still 2, regardless of endianness).